# Is there a way to prevent Andorid/iOS taking control over a video played inline on my website

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, html5-video, media

I have a video on my website that I need to keep "locked" (visitors shouldn't be able to play/pause/forward).

I noticed that if I flip my phone the video goes full-screen and the OS takes control of it (it's no longer played by the inline html player, but instead is played by the OS player).

Any way to prevent that?

```
<video playsinline webkit-playsinline>
    ...
</video>
```

PS: I tried the playsinline attribute, but it didn't seem to work. At least not on the devices I tested.